# convert xml string to datatable using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to convert following xml string into datatable. Please suggest me any solution to do that

**XMLString :**

```
 0
 <Seat-Map> 
  <Lower-Deck>
    <column id="1"> 
        <row id="1"><seat number="1C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="2"><seat number="2C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="3"><seat number="3C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="4"><seat number="4C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="5"><seat number="5C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="6"><seat number="6C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="7"><seat number="7C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="8"><seat number="8C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="9"><seat number="9C" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="10"><seat number="10C" status="0" /> </row> 
    </column>
    <column id="2"> 
        <row id="1"><seat number="1B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="2"><seat number="2B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="3"><seat number="3B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="4"><seat number="4B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="5"><seat number="5B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="6"><seat number="6B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="7"><seat number="7B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="8"><seat number="8B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="9"><seat number="9B" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="10"><seat number="10B" status="0" /> </row> 
    </column>
    <column id="3"> 
        <row id="1"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="2"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="3"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="4"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="5"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="6"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="7"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="8"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="9"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
        <row id="10"><seat number="#" status="blank"/> </row> 
    </column>
    <column id="4"> 
        <row id="1"><seat number="1A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="2"><seat number="2A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="3"><seat number="3A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="4"><seat number="4A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="5"><seat number="5A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="6"><seat number="6A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="7"><seat number="7A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="8"><seat number="8A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="9"><seat number="9A" status="0" /> </row> 
        <row id="10"><seat number="10A" status="0" /> </row> 
    </column> 
  </Lower-Deck>
</Seat-Map>
```

**I am using following Code :**

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader( Here I am passing xml string);
ds.ReadXml(stringReader);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

**Output I am getting**

```
errorCode             |         xml
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                     |  <Seat-Map><Lower-Deck><column id="1"><row id="1">..............
                      |  ....................</Lower-Deck></Seat-Map>
```

**But I need following DataTable from that XML String :**

```
public static DataTable querySeat(string bus_id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;
        dc = new DataColumn("column", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dc = new DataColumn("row", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add("seat"); // Seat Label
        dc = new DataColumn("deck", Type.GetType("System.Int32")); // Deck, 1 = Lower Deck, 2 = Upper Deck
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add("status"); // Status, 1 = Available, 0 = Taken
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: What is the database engine you are using man?

Comment: I am not using any database that xml string getting some other API ( response ).

Comment: I'm just trying to understand. So you just need to convert the Xml string to a DataTable type?

Comment: Yes but i need following columns : column, row, seat, deck , status it means 1, 1, 1c, 1, 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I hope this helps. The way I've done it is to parse the Xml and load it to a DOM (here I'm using LinqToXml), then try to find all the seats and insert them to an instance of a DataTable.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string XmlData = @"<Seat-Map>
  <Lower-Deck>
    <column id=""1""> 
        <row id=""1""><seat number=""1C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""2""><seat number=""2C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""3""><seat number=""3C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""4""><seat number=""4C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""5""><seat number=""5C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""6""><seat number=""6C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""7""><seat number=""7C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""8""><seat number=""8C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""9""><seat number=""9C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""10""><seat number=""10C"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
    </column>
    <column id=""2""> 
        <row id=""1""><seat number=""1B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""2""><seat number=""2B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""3""><seat number=""3B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""4""><seat number=""4B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""5""><seat number=""5B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""6""><seat number=""6B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""7""><seat number=""7B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""8""><seat number=""8B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""9""><seat number=""9B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""10""><seat number=""10B"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
    </column>
    <column id=""3""> 
        <row id=""1""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""2""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""3""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""4""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""5""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""6""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""7""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""8""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""9""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
        <row id=""10""><seat number=""#"" status=""blank""/> </row> 
    </column>
    <column id=""4""> 
        <row id=""1""><seat number=""1A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""2""><seat number=""2A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""3""><seat number=""3A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""4""><seat number=""4A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""5""><seat number=""5A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""6""><seat number=""6A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""7""><seat number=""7A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""8""><seat number=""8A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""9""><seat number=""9A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
        <row id=""10""><seat number=""10A"" status=""0"" /> </row> 
    </column> 
  </Lower-Deck>
</Seat-Map>"
;

            DataTable result = new DataTable("SeatData");

            DataColumn columnColumn = result.Columns.Add("column", typeof(Int32));

            DataColumn rowColumn = result.Columns.Add("row", typeof(Int32));

            DataColumn seatColumn = result.Columns.Add("seat", typeof(String));

            DataColumn deckColumn = result.Columns.Add("deck", typeof(Int32));

            DataColumn statusColumn = result.Columns.Add("status", typeof(Int32));

            XElement.Parse(
                XmlData
            )
            .Descendants("seat")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(
                (element) =>
                {
                    DataRow row = result.NewRow();

                    row.SetField<int>(columnColumn, Convert.ToInt32(element.Parent.Parent.Attribute("id").Value));

                    row.SetField<int>(rowColumn, Convert.ToInt32(element.Parent.Attribute("id").Value));

                    row.SetField<string>(seatColumn, element.Attribute("number").Value);

                    int deckNo = -1;

                    if (element.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name.LocalName == "Lower-Deck")

                        deckNo = 1;

                    row.SetField<int>(deckColumn, deckNo);

                    string statusString = element.Attribute("status").Value;
                    int statusValue = -1;

                    if (statusString == "blank")

                        statusValue = 1;

                    else if (statusString == "0")

                        statusValue = 0;

                    row.SetField<int>(statusColumn, statusValue);

                    result.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            );


            result.AsEnumerable()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(
                (row) =>
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

A few things to consider:

> 1. The data you have provided in the Xml data was not match with the mentioned definition. So you might want to update the question.
> 2. I would rather have the seat number, status, row and deck id's as foreign keys for the seat object (element).
> 3. Be aware of the using statements above the code if you wanted to use it.

Comment: Thank you Rikki for helping me.